# Using "<nul set /P" giving syntax errors when nested in an If Statement within Batch File

Tags: batch-file, windows-10

Consider the following `If Statement` from a `Batch File` which produces `The syntax of the command is incorrect` when the `set /p` line is used inside. . .:

```cmd
 @ECHO ON
 <nul (set /p "lineOut=A TEST OF THE SET /P PROTOCOL")>>%log%
 <nul set /p "lineOut=A TEST OF THE SET /P PROTOCOL2">>%log%
 If "%~1"=="1" (
   REM If I want to standardize the size of the bar to 40 segments (columns) to fit within text in current tool setting specify "1" as Arg 1 and # of Columns as Arg 2 (40).
   set "progBar.barArea=%~2"
   <nul set /p "lineOut=progBar.barArea set to width of arg 2.!cr!!lf!">>%log%
   set "progBar.initState=1"   
 )
```

I'm using this approach to append a log file as it's much faster than using `echo` to do it, and it works just fine in all of the other `If Statements` that I'm using.  `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions` is set globally at the beginning of the batch file, no `endlocal` commands in place.  I have tried `<nul (set /p "lineOut=Text. . .")>>%log%` as well, but something does not seem to be in the right place.

Looking at the output by enabling `@Echo On` I can see this when it's in place with no parentheses (it matches the test line above it):

> ```
> set /p "lineOut=progBar.barArea set to width of arg 2.!cr!!lf!" 0<nul 1>>"C:\Users. . . Filename.log"
>
> set /p "lineOut=A TEST OF THE SET /P PROTOCOL2" 0<nul 1>>"C:\Users\. . .Filename.log"
> ```

With the parentheses added, I get this (which matches the test line above it):

> ```
> (set /p "lineOut=progBar.barArea set to width of arg 2.!cr!!lf!" ) 0<nul 1>>"C:\Users\. . .Filename.log"
>
> (set /p "lineOut=A TEST OF THE SET /P PROTOCOL" ) 0<nul 1>>"C:\Users\. . .Filename.log"
> ```

I have tried escaping `^<nul (set /p "lineOut=Text")` I've tried escaping the parentheses: `<nul ^(set /p "lineOut=Text"^)>>%log%` thinking maybe the parentheses were causing a problem in this case. . .

For what it is worth, `%~1` is not empty, but `%~2` is.  I have even removed the `set "progBar.barArea=%~2"` line without any success.  I only get rid of this error when I remove the `set /p` line.

> ```
> C:\Users\path>(set /p "lineOut=A TEST OF THE SET /P PROTOCOL" ) 0<nul 1>>"C:\Users. . .Filename.log"
>
> C:\Users\path>set /p "lineOut=A TEST OF THE SET /P PROTOCOL2" 0<nul 1>>"C:\Users. . .Filename.log"
>
> C:\Users\path>If "3" == "1" (
> REM If I want to standardize the size of the bar to 40 segments (columns) to fit within text in current tool setting specify "1" as Arg 1 and # of Columns as Arg 2.
>  set "progBar.barArea="  <<< This line makes no difference.
>  (set /p "lineOut=progBar.barArea set to width of arg 2.!cr!!lf!" ) 0<nul 1>>"C:\Users. . .Filename.log"
>  set "progBar.initState=1"
> )
> The syntax of the command is incorrect.
> ```

What am I missing?

### Update 1

As suggested by @Magoo in a comment, I tried just escaping the ending parenthesis as follows: `<nul (set /p "lineOut=progBar barArea set to width of arg 2.!cr!!lf!"^)`

The output for the *entire* `If Statement` disappears entirely now, while the error remains.

> ```
> C:\Users\path>(set /p "lineOut=A TEST OF THE SET /P PROTOCOL" ) 0<nul 1>>"C:\Users. . .Filename.log"
>
> C:\Users\path>set /p "lineOut=A TEST OF THE SET /P PROTOCOL2" 0<nul 1>>"C:\Users. . .Filename.log"
> The syntax of the command is incorrect.
> ```

### Update 2

Thinking the same thing as @jeb did in the comments, I removed the `REM` line containing the `)` entirely to see if this was a problem (I knew there were some edge cases were this happens). . .  Sadly - this made no difference.

Updated Code:

```cmd
 @ECHO ON
 <nul (set /p "lineOut=A TEST OF THE SET /P PROTOCOL")>>%log%
 <nul set /p "lineOut=A TEST OF THE SET /P PROTOCOL2">>%log%
 If "%~1"=="1" (
   
   set "progBar.barArea=%~2"
   <nul (set /p "lineOut=progBar barArea set to width of arg 2.!cr!!lf!")>>%log%
   set "progBar.initState=1"
   
 )
```

Updated Output:

> ```
> C:\Users\path>(set /p "lineOut=A TEST OF THE SET /P PROTOCOL" ) 0<nul 1>>"C:\Users. . .Filename.log"
>
> C:\Users\path>set /p "lineOut=A TEST OF THE SET /P PROTOCOL2" 0<nul 1>>"C:\Users. . .Filename.log"
>
> C:\Users\path>If "3" == "1" (
> set "progBar.barArea="
>  (set /p "lineOut=progBar barArea set to width of arg 2.!cr!!lf!" ) 0<nul 1>>"C:\Users. . .Filename.log"
>  set "progBar.initState=1"
> )
> The syntax of the command is incorrect.
> ```

[image: Here's a screenshot showing the same output. . . I think I'm losing my mind! What is wrong with this?]

### Possible Workaround . . . might just be cleaner

While I intend to make a workaround for this (setting the value of a string in the `If Statement` and then using the `<nul (set /p "lineOut=Text")>>%log%` method to send the output of the string to the log file, I'm genuinely baffled at why this specific `If Statement` is failing - I have nearly countless others with almost identical construction where it works fine.

Comment: Probably, as a first guess, you need to escape the `)` character with a caret if it is  inside the parenthesised block

Comment: @Magoo, alas, I have tried this too, to no avail.  I'll test it once more just in case I'm losing my mind - if it produces something different _this time_ then I'll  post it as the answer.

Comment: The closing parenthesis in the `REM` are the problems

Comment: @jeb - I had already tried that by the time I saw your comment - to no avail.  I have another hypothesis that I'm going to test next. . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## I FOUND IT.

Since nothing I did to this initial `If Statement` made a difference to the outcome . . . I finally performed what I ***normally*** do to debug my code (adding an `echo statement` after `every line of other code` to see where the code was ***REALLY*** breaking. . .) no clue why I didn't just do this to start with). . . Lo and behold . . . it's RIGHT THERE.  This whole time.  I forgot to add a closing quote to the **NEXT** `If Statement` which prevented the code from executing further. It wasn't until I saw the output that I finally found it.  (See output below)  Though I'm kicking myself rather fiercely right now, I guess the ***real lesson here is***:

> #### When you develop a method to debug your code which has usually produced good results for you, don't deviate from that method unless it fails first.

Demonstration of my method:

```cmd
 @ECHO ON
 <nul (set /p "lineOut=A TEST OF THE SET /P PROTOCOL")>>%log%
 <nul set /p "lineOut=A TEST OF THE SET /P PROTOCOL2">>%log%
 Echo SanityCheck 1
 If "%~1"=="1" (
 Echo SanityCheck 2
   REM If I want to standardize the size of the bar to 40 segments (columns) to fit within text in current tool setting specify "1" as Arg 1 and # of Columns as Arg 2.
 Echo SanityCheck 3
   set "progBar.barArea=%~2"
 Echo SanityCheck 4
   <nul (set /p "lineOut=progBar.barArea set to width of arg 2.!cr!!lf!")>>%log%
 Echo SanityCheck 5
   set "progBar.initState=1"
 Echo SanityCheck 6   
 )
 Echo SanityCheck 7
 If "%~1"=="2" (
 Echo SanityCheck 8
   REM If I want to set the bar to be CMD window size dependent but only extend across half of the screen and leave room for text, specify "2" as Arg 1
 Echo SanityCheck 9
   set "progBar.segments="
 Echo SanityCheck 10
   Call :GetConsoleWidth "progBar.segments"
 Echo SanityCheck 11
   set /a "progBar.barArea=progBar.segments/2-2"
 Echo SanityCheck 12
   REM The Line Below this is the problem.  I forgot the closing Double Quote!
   <nul (set /p "lineOut=progBar.barArea set to half Console Width.)>>%log%
 Echo SanityCheck 13
   set "progBar.initState=2"
 Echo SanityCheck 14
 )
 Echo SanityCheck 15
```

Output to the modified code above:

> ```
> C:\Users\path>(set /p "lineOut=A TEST OF THE SET /P PROTOCOL" ) 0<nul 1>>"C:\Users. . .Filename.log"
>
> C:\Users\path>set /p "lineOut=A TEST OF THE SET /P PROTOCOL2" 0<nul 1>>"C:\Users. . .Filename.log"
>
> C:\Users\path>Echo SanityCheck 1
> SanityCheck 1
>
> C:\Users\path>If "3" == "1" (
> Echo SanityCheck 2
>  REM If I want to standardize the size of the bar to 40 segments (columns) to fit within text in current tool setting specify "1" as Arg 1 and # of Columns as Arg 2.
>  Echo SanityCheck 3
>  set "progBar.barArea="
>  Echo SanityCheck 4
>  (set /p "lineOut=progBar.barArea set to width of arg 2.!cr!!lf!" ) 0<nul 1>>"C:\Users. . .Filename.log"
>  Echo SanityCheck 5
>  set "progBar.initState=1"
>  Echo SanityCheck 6
> )
>
> C:\Users\path>Echo SanityCheck 7
> SanityCheck 7
> The syntax of the command is incorrect.
> ```